# ASP/Entity : Object Reference Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have already have a look at such posts like: [Object Reference Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937258/null-object-reference-error) but still cannot find the answer I am looking for.

```
foreach (var test in (gathered as tblbus_address).Address1)
```

returns this error:

> *System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

I have tried checking if it is null before:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty((gathered as tblbus_address).Address1){}
```

*I have tried adding `ToString();` and making sure it is `!=null;`*

**However, even after all this, I receive the same error.**

Comment: Are you sure `gathered` is not null?

Comment: @Zippy gathered probably isn't a `tblbus_address`, then `as` returns null.

Comment: @AlexanderDerck that can be true too. OP check if `gathered` is not null and if it's of type `tblbus_address` too.

Comment: @Zippy I added: `if (gathered != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty((gathered as tblbus_address).Address1)){}` and nothing

Comment: Could you show us what is the type of `gathered`?

Comment: @Zippy sure: `var gathered = (from c in db.tblbus_address where c.BusinessID == queryID && c.AddressTypeID == addrnum select c);`

Comment: And what does that query return?

Comment: Should be an Object of the Database showing all the data from the Query but I've stopped it and this is what it holds: https://gyazo.com/8474dc9eb382e923ae65e2a5d648fd9e

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing too many things in foreach statement. Rather split it up, this way you can neatly handle the null checks rather than getting the null reference exception.

```
var address = gathered as tblbus_address
if(address!=null && address.Address1 !=null)
{
  foreach (var test in address.Address1)
  {
    //do your stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: I will try this now, thank-you.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you

```
var data=gathered;
if(data!=null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(data.Address1))
{
foreach (var test in (data as tblbus_address).Address1)
}
```